# Adding numbers in a list and converting it to a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm sure this must be simple, but I'm a python noob, so I need some help.
I have a list that looks the following way:

```
foo = [['0.125', '0', 'able'], ['', '0.75', 'unable'], ['0', '0', 'dorsal'], ['0', '0', 'ventral'], ['0', '0', 'acroscopic']]
```

Notice that every word has 1 or 2 numbers to it. I want to substract number 2 from number 1 and then come with a **dictionary** that is: word, number.
Foo would then look something like this:

```
foo = {'able','0.125'},{'unable', '-0.75'}...
```

it tried doing:

```
bar=[]
for a,b,c in foo:
   d=float(a)-float(b)
   bar.append((c,d))
```

But I got the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: That's from the entry `['', '0.75', 'unable']`. Try `float(a or 0)` to treat empty strings as 0

Comment: The result `foo` in your example appears to actually be a tuple of sets, not a dictionary. A dictionary is `{key: value, key2: value}` not `{key, value}, {key2, value2}`

Answer (score 3):

`''` cannot be converted to string.

```
bar = []
for a,b,c in foo:
    d = float(a or 0) - float(b or 0)
    bar.append((c,d))
```

However, that will not make a dictionary. For that you want:

```
bar = {}
for a,b,c in foo:
    d = float(a or 0)-float(b or 0)
    bar[c] = d
```

Or a shorter way using dictionary comprehensions:

```
bar = {sublist[2]: float(sublist[0] or 0) - float(sublist[1] or 0) for sublist in foo}
```

Comment: this seems to work perfectly, only when I attempt to use bar outside the for loop, it gives me a "ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack" error, any ideas?

Comment: How are you using bar?

Comment: Dictionaries should be used like this: `var = dictionary[key]` and `dictionary[key] = value`

Comment: Or if you want to use `map`, `dict(map(lambda x: (x[2], float(x[1] or 0)-float(x[0] or 0), foo)))`.

Comment: well in the next step, i'd like to enter a string, and look it up word for word in bar, if it's in there, the value of bar needs to be added to a grand counter.

Comment: What do you mean by the value of bar?

Comment: Is this what you want?
`s = input("Enter a string");
counter += bar.get(s,0);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to verify if the string is empty like that '' and convert it to 0

Answer (score 0):

`float('')` doesn't work. Assuming you want `0` in that case, I recommend a helper function:

```
def safefloat(s):
    if not s: 
        return 0.0
    return float(s)

res = {}
for a, b, c in foo:
    res[c] = safefloat(a) - safefloat(b)
```

Note you can make the dictionary in one line with a comprehension:

```
res = dict((c, safefloat(a) - safefloat(b)) for a, b, c in foo)
```

or a dict comprehension in Python 2.7+:

```
res = {c: safefloat(a) - safefloat(b) for a, b, c in foo}
```

Answer (score 0):

that happens because in some cases their is an empty string 
you could write

```
d = float(a or '0') - float(b or '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> foo = [['0.125', '0', 'able'], ['', '0.75', 'unable'],
           ['0', '0', 'dorsal'], ['0', '0', 'ventral'],
           ['0', '0', 'acroscopic']]
>>> dict((i[2], float(i[0] or 0) - float(i[1])) for i in foo)
{'acroscopic': 0.0, 'ventral': 0.0, 'unable': -0.75, 'able': 0.125,
 'dorsal': 0.0}
```